# tablesorter not sorting updated rows correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm working on a personal project, and I am having trouble getting my 5th column to sort properly in Chrome using tablesorter. <strike>I made a jsfiddle for this and it works fine in it.</strike>

Can someone maybe point me in the right direction to fix this <strike>and explain why the jsfiddle works, but chrome alone doesn't</strike>?

Here's the jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/3rbp6okz/

Here is the full file:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Dark Insanity Guild Roster</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq/tablesorter-master/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq/tablesorter-master/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
    <script>
    var playernamelink = [];
    var playername = [];
    var playerclass =[];
    var playerspec =[];
    var playerlvl =[];
    var playerilvl =[];
    var playerrealm =[];
    var totalPlayers = 0;
    //start data pull
    pull();
    //get the data from battle.net
    function pull()
    {   
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'https://us.api.battle.net/wow/guild/Sen\'jin/dark%20insanity?fields=members&locale=en_US&jsonp=guilddata&apikey=tfawppjfe9aj9zd5pudqv76x86fhbnpe',
                type:"GET",
                data: { fields: "members" },
                dataType: "jsonp",
                contentType:"application/json",
                jsonpCallback:"guilddata",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    for(var i in data.members)
                    {
                        playernamelink[i] = '<a href="http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/' +fixRealm(data.members[i].character.realm)+ '/' + data.members[i].character.name + '/simple" target=_blank>'+ data.members[i].character.name + '</a>';
                        playername[i] = data.members[i].character.name;
                        playerclass[i] = getClass(data.members[i].character.class);
                        playerspec[i] = (data.members[i].character.spec ? data.members[i].character.spec.name : "");
                        playerlvl[i] = data.members[i].character.level;
                        playerrealm[i] = fixRealm(data.members[i].character.realm);
                        totalPlayers++;
                    };
                },
                complete: function(data)
                {
                    for(var i = 0; i < totalPlayers; i++)
                    {
                    //only make API call if player level is 110
                        if(playerlvl[i] == '110')
                        {
                            getIlvl(playerrealm[i], playername[i], i);
                        }   
                    }
                    populateTable();
                }
            }
        );
    }
    //call the api to get players Ilvl
    function getIlvl(realm,player,index)
    {
        var ilvl;
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                //https://us.api.battle.net/wow/character/sen'jin/Palador?fields=items&locale=en_US&apikey=tfawppjfe9aj9zd5pudqv76x86fhbnpe
                url: 'https://us.api.battle.net/wow/character/'+realm+'/'+player+'?fields=items&locale=en_US&json=player&apikey=tfawppjfe9aj9zd5pudqv76x86fhbnpe',
                type:"GET",
                data2: {fields: "items"},
                dataType: "json",
                contentType:"application/json",
                jsonpCallback:"player",
                success: function(data2)
                {
                    //console.log(data2);
                    //console.log(data2.items.averageItemLevel);
                    ilvl = data2.items.averageItemLevel;
                },
                complete: function(data)
                {
                    playerilvl[index] = ilvl;
                    //UPDATE cell with Ilvl
                    var x = document.getElementById("players").rows[index].cells;
                    x[4].innerHTML = playerilvl[index];
                }
            }
        );
    }
    //format realm string for URL
    function fixRealm(realm)
    {
        return (realm == 'Sen\'jin') ? 'Sen\'jin' : 'Quel\'dorei';
    }
    //return class string
    function getClass(classNumber)
        {
            switch(classNumber)
            {
                case(1):
                    return 'Warrior';
                break;
                case(2):
                    return 'Paladin';
                break;
                case(3):
                    return 'Hunter';
                break;
                case(4):
                    return 'Rogue';
                break;
                case(5):
                    return 'Priest';
                break;
                case(6):
                    return 'Death Knight';
                break;
                case(7):
                    return 'Shaman';
                break;
                case(8):
                    return 'Mage';
                break;
                case(9):
                    return 'Warlock';
                break;
                case(10):
                    return 'Monk';
                break;
                case(11):
                    return 'Druid';
                break;
                case(12):
                    return 'Demon Hunter';
                break;
            }
        }
    //populate table with data after completed API call to guild data
    function populateTable()
    {

        var tableRef = document.getElementById('players').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        for(var i = 1; i < totalPlayers; i++)
        {
            var row = tableRef.insertRow();
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            cell1.innerHTML = playernamelink[i];
            cell2.innerHTML = playerclass[i];
            cell3.innerHTML = playerspec[i];
            cell4.innerHTML = playerlvl[i];
            cell5.innerHTML = '0';
        }
        //initialize tablesorter
        $("#players").tablesorter({
            headers: {
                4: {
                     sorter: "digit"
                }
            }
       });
    }
    </script>

    </head>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Ambassador RickFace\Desktop\web\jq\tablesorter-master\themes\blue\style.css">
    -->
    <body>
    <h1>Dark Insanity Guild Members</h1><br>
    <table id="players" class="tablesorter">
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Specialization</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Item Level</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
    </tbody>  
    </table>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works in JSFiddle, but not on your page because the javascript is run before the `<body>` has completed loading. Either move all your javascript to the bottom of the page, above the `</body>` tag, or wrap the javascript in a document ready function:

```
$(function() {
    // add all your javascript here
});
```

Edit: Oh and the parser name is "digit" not "integer":

```
{ 4: {sorter:"digit"} }
```

Edit2: Your fiddle is loading tablesorter twice and initializing it a bunch of times inside the for loop - [here is an updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/3rbp6okz/2/) and the fixed loops code:

```
function populateTable() {

  var tableRef = document.getElementById('players').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < totalPlayers; i++) {
    var row = tableRef.insertRow();
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell1.innerHTML = playernamelink[i];
    cell2.innerHTML = playerclass[i];
    cell3.innerHTML = playerspec[i];
    cell4.innerHTML = playerlvl[i];
    cell5.innerHTML = '0';
  }
  //initialize tablesorter
  $("#players").tablesorter({
    headers: {
      4: {
        sorter: "digit"
      }
    }
  });
}
```

---

Update 2: Oh, I missed the fact that more asynchronous data was being loaded within the ajax complete callback. I think the easiest solution would be to set up some promises and then in the `done` function, update tablesorter ([updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/3rbp6okz/3/)):

```
var items = [];
function getIlvl(realm, player, index) {
  var ilvl;
  items.push($.ajax({...}));
  // ...
}

function populateTable() {
  // ...
  $.when.apply($, items).done(function() {
    $('#players').trigger('update');
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, moving the script to the bottom of the body and/or changing integer to digit still gave the same results. I edited my question since I double checked the jsfiddle and it's actually not working there either!

Comment: That edit drastically increased the page load and sorting, but the Item Level column still isn't sorting correctly, even in the updated demo link. When you click the "item Level" header, is it sorting correctly for you?

I have some of the 5th column values updating after the initial page loads. Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: Please check my updated answer... I don't know why load/sorting took so much longer... try setting the `debug` option to see if the problem is tablesorter.

Comment: Loading tablesorter over 600 times in the old populateTable() for loop may have been the culprit for the loading and sorting times. Your updated answer has mostly corrected the problem. The last row is now sorting properly with exception of a single random value each time the page loads. I'll debug it and see why it isn't updating that value. Thank you again for helping!

Comment: You're welcome! If speed is still a problem, don't use `.insertRow()` and `insertCell()`, instead build an HTML string (e.g. `html += "<tr><td>...</td></tr>"`) then use `tableRef.innerHTML = html;`. Basically minimize DOM interactions.